# Does Rich Snippets error messages prevent new SERP display appearing?

Tags: seo, google, rich-snippets

Using the Google Structured Data Testing Tool (`www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets`) I input the following URL:

`http://www.eggrecipes.co.uk/recipes/arrabiatta-ham-egg-pizza`

and it shows "Arrabiatta ham & egg pizza", however when I Google this it doesn't show with rich snippets.

I know it MAY be an indexing issue (even though it has been a few weeks), however on the tool I get the following message:

> Error: We did not accept "5 mins" as cooking time. Error: Cooking time
>   should be in ISO 8601 format -
>   http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#duration

Would this affect it?

I have previously ignored it since the preview shows fine with the correct total time (15 mins).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, errors reported by Google in the [Structured Data Testing Tool](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets) will cause your rich snippets to be missing in your search engine results snippet, as can be seen [here](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets?q=http://www.eggrecipes.co.uk/recipes/arrabiatta-ham-egg-pizza) (providing Google retains the test results).

To correct this, you'll need to specify the times in [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format for [Durations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations), by changing the following:

`5 mins -> PT5M` 
`10 mins -> PT10M`

This will then correct the error, as can be seen [here](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets?q=uploaded:8004e7e82d2424eb99060d4ca72a0482) (providing Google retains the test results). After correcting this in your pages, you should request Google to re-crawl them using the [Fetch as Google](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/158587?hl=en) tool.

Comment: Seems the URL in the question is no longer working. Is this question resolved now? Seems to be since the error will no longer appear in the testing tool.